# Convert Python string into Raw Form

Tags: python

```
class FrozenDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,default=None):
        if default: self.update(default)
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)


dictionary={FrozenDict({"dsa":"saas"}):"Hi"}

eval(str(dictionary))


TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I am trying to convert a string into its 'raw' form, so I do not get an error. The 'raw' form of dictionary would be `{FrozenDict({"dsa":"saas"}):"Hi"}`

Something like this:

```
eval(rawform(dictionary))
```

would be awesome..

Edit:

OrderedDict seems to work, does anyone know why?

Edit:

This is what I am trying to load using pickle.loads

```
S'{\'Source\': {\'CollideObjects\': [], \'Depth\': 0, \'Events\': OrderedDict([(({\'function\': \'bi_create\', \'class\': \'\', \'name\': \'Create\'}, 0), {{\'data\': {\'raw\': \'Set saddasdsadsa to: (,)\', \'data\': {u\'function\': u\'asddsaadsasddsasdasdasddsasdasda(x=None,y=None)\', u\'src\': u\'GUI\\\\movetoxy.xml\', \'code\': u\'\\nreal=[0,0]\\ncurrent=self.sdsdadsaadssd()\\nif x!=None:\\n\\treal[0]=float(x)\\nelse:\\n\\treal[0]=current[1]\\nif y!=None:\\n\\treal[1]=float(y)\\nelse:\\n\\treal[1]=current[1]\\nself.SetPos(*real)\\n\', \'return\': u"\'Set Position to: (\'+str(x)+\',\'+str(y)+\')\'", u\'title\': u\'Set Position\', u\'image\': u\'modules\\\\Core\\\\images\\\\pos.png\', \'dddddddddd\': u\'self.SetPosition(,)\', \'html\': u\'C:\\\\sadsdadsad\\\\dsasasddsa\\\\modules\\\\Core\\\\GUI\\\\movetoxy.xml\', \'apply\': {\'name\': \'Self\', \'value\': \'\'}, u\'holder\': u\'False\', u\'class\': u\'object\'}, \'dialog\': u\'Set Position\', \'name_var\': {u\'y\': {\'class\': u\'wxTextCtrl\', \'value\': u\'\'}, u\'x\': {\'class\': u\'wxTextCtrl\', \'value\': u\'\'}}}}: {}})]), \'Sprite\': \'\'}, \'Window\': \'\', \'Type\': \'Object\', \'Name\': u\'Object1\', \'Id\': 1}'
```

Comment: Do not just return `id(self)` for the `__hash__`; that makes your keys impossible to locate again.

Comment: Hmm, I got that from the internet, Do you have any suggestions on what I should change instead?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__ on what a `__hash__` method should do.

Comment: You need to take the hash values of your contained keys and values into account *and* you must make sure that the values are hashable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create "rawform", you need to override `__repr__`:

```
class FrozenDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,default=None):
        if default: self.update(default)
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "FrozenDict(%s)" % dict.__repr__(self)


print FrozenDict({"dsa":"saas"})

dictionary={FrozenDict({"dsa":"saas"}):"Hi"}

print eval(str(dictionary))
```

The result I get:

```
FrozenDict({'dsa': 'saas'})
{FrozenDict({'dsa': 'saas'}): 'Hi'}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose, is there any reason you couldn't `pickle` it instead?

```
import cPickle as pickle
# This can't be `eval`d, but...
string = pickle.dumps(dictionary)
# ... you can use it to get back the original object
obj = pickle.loads(string)
```

Of course, it doesn't make use of `eval`, but if the use of `eval` can be avoided, it ought to be.

Comment: Im actually storing dictionary in a sqlite3 table and when I load the dictionary from the table, I get,  `TypeError: must be string, not unicode`, Do you know the best way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example of the data for which you're having the issue and then we can more easily diagnose :-)

Comment: @AA: sounds like you possibly want a BLOB type column instead of encoding text in the database.

Comment: @AA: A `sqlite` text column is a unicode value. You could *also* consider JSON to store these. `import json; json.dumps(dictionary)`; the JSON library can handle both Unicode and byte string inputs. Otherwise, your options are to use a BLOB type, or convert the unicode back to a byte string before unpickling.

Comment: Thanks guys but Im gonna with marc's answer because it seems to be a quick fix. I really appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with what you're doing.

First off, the reason that your `eval` doesn't work is because you have not overridden the `__repr__` method in your `FrozenDict` class, so `eval` is producing a regular dictionary rather than a new `FrozenDict` and getting an error when trying to use it as a dictionary key. This is relatively easy to fix:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "FrozenDict({})".format(super(FrozenDict, self).__repr__())
```

This will let you use the `str` or `repr` of your object as Python code to recreate it.

However, there are some other issues that this doesn't fix. For instance, currently you can have dictionaries that hash differently even though they compare as equal:

```
a = FrozenDict({"foo":"bar"})
b = FrozenDict({"foo":"bar"})

a == b             # True!
hash(a) == hash(b) # False!
```

This makes it impossible to match your frozen dictionary in a hash table if you don't have exactly the same object you used when you inserted it.

A better approach would probably compute a hash based on the keys and values that were in the dictionary. Something like this will do better:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(sorted(self.items()))
```

However, now you'll run into another issue: Your dictionary is mutable, and its hash can change if you add or remove values from it. This is very bad:

```
a = FrozenDict()
d = {a: "a"}

a["foo"] = "bar"

d[a]            # raises a KeyError!
d[FrozenDict()] # perhaps surprisingly, so does this!
```

To fix this you'll probably need to override `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` and `update` to raise exceptions when they're called. I suppose if you know that you won't be modifying the values after adding them to the dictionary you could skip this, but if you want your class to be more generally useful it's necessary. There might be some other mutation methods that I've forgotten too.